# Check and compare if time difference is less than 30 sec between all rows of a column based on another column

Tags: bash, csv, awk

In a shell script, I want to get all the records, if from file orders it contains 3 or more rows where firm is same and time (column2) difference is less than 30 seconds, if greater than 30 seconds than we exclude. I have tried using awk, but to no avail.

The file `orders.csv` will have hundreds of rows:

```
date,time,firm,user,id
20220520,12:00:00,TEST1,ABC,FNT0060
20220520,12:00:05,TEST2,ABC,FNT0061
20220520,12:00:10,TEST1,ABC,FNT0062
20220520,12:00:25,TEST1,ABC,FNT0063
20220520,12:00:45,TEST1,ABC,FNT0064
...
```

Expected output:

```
date,time,firm,user,id
20220520,12:00:00,TEST1,ABC,FNT0060
20220520,12:00:10,TEST1,ABC,FNT0062
20220520,12:00:25,TEST1,ABC,FNT0063
```

Also, if for instance time in seconds in time column, "01 02 29 31 32" for the same frim, then it's fine either way we print 01,02,29 as only set or would print all records since we have 2 sets. 01 02 29 & 29 31 32 since both are at the moment.

I can get the time difference in time of a column alone, but not in comparison to above mentioned case:

```bash
awk -F '[:,]' '{t=$2x3600+$3x60+$4} NR>1{printf( "%.6f\n", t-p)}{p=t}' $orders.csv > abc.csv
```

Now `abc.csv` contains "10,15"

The following command will get me 3 or more matching firm:

```bash
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$3]++; next} cnt[$3]>=3' $orders.csv $orders.csv > firm.csv
```

Now, how can I combine such that I get expected result or any other way?

Comment: are all lines guaranteed to have the same `date`? if not, then you also need to take into consideration the difference in date when calculating the 30-second difference ... right?

Comment: yes, guaranteed to have same date. only need to take time into consideration.

Comment: "difference is less than 30 seconds if greater than 30 seconds than we exclude" what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**input_file**

```
date,time,firm,user,id
20220520,12:00:00,TEST1,ABC,FNT0060
20220520,12:00:05,TEST2,ABC,FNT0061
20220520,12:00:10,TEST1,ABC,FNT0062
20220520,12:00:25,TEST1,ABC,FNT0063
20220520,12:00:45,TEST1,ABC,FNT0064
```

---

**Code**

```
awk -F, '
 function toSeconds(t){  
    cmd="date -d " "\"" t "\""  " +%s"                         # convert date to seconds
    cmd | getline seconds;
    close(cmd);
    return seconds  
}
NR==1{
    print                                                       # if line 1 print header
}
NR>1{                                                           # if not header line create array
    a[$3][NR]["time"]=$1" "$2                                        # map firm->linenumber->time = value $1" "$2                                        
    a[$3][NR]["row"]=$0                                         # map firm->linenumber->row = value $0
}
END{
    for(firm in a){                                             # iterating main array a
        if (length(a[firm]) > 3){                               # geting firm length. only if greater 3
            i=1
            for (n in a[firm]){                                 # iterating firm array a[firm]
                if (i==1) time = a[firm][n]["time"]                     # set init time from first firm row
                diff = (toSeconds(a[firm][n]["time"]) - toSeconds(time))  # get diff time (row time and init time) 
                if (diff >= 0 && diff < 30 ) print a[firm][n]["row"]                 # print the complete row saved in array 
                i++                                                       # if deiff less than 30                              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### ' input_file

**Output**

```
date,time,firm,user,id
20220520,12:00:00,TEST1,ABC,FNT0060
20220520,12:00:10,TEST1,ABC,FNT0062
20220520,12:00:25,TEST1,ABC,FNT0063
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i only get first row printed. is it because of NR==1?

Comment: @AdIl  i used your input_file und got this. NR==1 prints the header the rest is printed in the "END" block

Comment: Code dumps are not so helpful without explanation of what they do...

Comment: yes above code works as indented. i had removed the header from my input file which is why it gave incorrect result.

Comment: @AdIl if you don't have a header you have to remove  `NR==1{...}` and `NR>1`

Comment: This doesn't work if the start time is shortly before midnight, for example ```20221231,23:59:50``` That requires doing math on the date as well.

Comment: @jb_dk changed.. converting date & time to seconds with date command

Comment: @ufopilot converting date & time to seconds with date command does not work. also what if there are miliseconds in question and i would like to get differentiate with 1 second instead? i tried adding following but does not work:
        split(t,b,"[:.]")
        return (b[1] * 3600) + (b[2] * 60) + (b[3] * 1000) + b[4]
also 
if (diff < 1000 ) print a[firm][n]["row"]
thanks!

Comment: @ufopilot i corrected it to return (b[1] * 3600000) + (b[2] * 60000) + (b[3] * 1000) + b[4], but getting empty file